# Insert values into a Table in MVC using MongoDb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have been trying to insert values in a table in mongoDB using MVC but I got stuck very early getting an error and could not resolve it.
The controller code is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(UserModel um)
{
    //Connect to MongoDB
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    var objDatabse = client.GetDatabase("MVCTestDB");

    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> UserDetails = objDatabse.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

    //Insert into Users table.
    UserDetails.Insert<UserModel>(um);
    return View();
}
```

I am getting an error at the line : MongoCollection UserDetails = objDatabse.GetCollection("Users");

The error is : "**cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase' to 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase'.An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)**" 
What I understand is there might be a type casting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHy not going for:

```
   IMongoCollection<UserModel> UserDetails = objDatabse.GetCollection<UserModel>("Users");

UserDetails.InsertOne(um);
```

**Here is working example from my code that is just tested (are you using the latest driver version):**

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

IMongoDatabase db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("Trading");

IMongoCollection<Account> = Database.GetCollection<Account>("Account");
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked :) :)
I had no idea about IMongoCollection. I am new to this